# Problems with insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables with relationship one-to-one:
http://i63.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0605/b8/2b2645b4fb0d34b93021aebd114f6fb8.jpg

I got form, where user type:
 - post title;
 - article;
 - and downloads an image to the server.

To work with db, i'm using PDO extension.
My model method to add post:

```
    public function add_post($title, $article, $user_id, $img_name) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Posts(title, article, user_id, post_time)
                    VALUES (:title, :article, :user_id, :post_time)";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ':title' => $title,
        ':article' => $article,
        ':user_id' => $user_id,
        ':post_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time() )
    ));
```

1. I want to insert into images table, image name and id of post what we adding, how can i add this id to the image table (Posts_id field)?
2. How can i do this with one query, if it's possible?
3. Is relationship one-to-one right? one post can have only 1 image.
Sorry for bad english! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can get the *last insert id* to get the id of the just inserted post. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php
2. No, this cannot be done in one query.
3. If one post can only have one image, then you might as well store the image in the same table as post (add the image columns to the posts table). Then you can also insert the image together with the other properties of post. The way you have it now, a post can have 0 or more images according to the database structure, although you can of course still enforce that there is always exactly one through your UI. 
   So one table is easier, two tables like you have now, is more flexible in case you want to keep the possibility open to have multiple images per post.

It's up to you what to choose, but I would choose to store it in one table for now. The two table setup adds complexitity which you don't need yet. Once you do, you can always migrate the data to another structure. Also, the two table structure is more flexible, but still it won't allow you, for instance, to store one image which can be shared between posts.

So, since you don't know whether you will be needing a more complex structure, nor what that structure will be, I would choose a single table approach and store the image with the post. See also [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).